# why Google News bot crawling my articles repeatedly?

Tags: google-news

I am showing the last 48 hours worth of articles in News Sitemap. My website got approved from Google and included in Google News, but the problem is Google News bot is crawling my previous articles again and again.

When I publish new article Google crawled my 1 or 2 previous articles along with the new article I published. I don't know why it's happening, can anyone tell me how can I resolve this issue?

my website [Egypt News](http://www.aiwaegypt.com/)

Comment: Why is this a problem? You can use robots.txt to disallow crawling previous articles if you really need to.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739561/google-news-bot-crawling-my-articles-repeatedly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. This topic might be on topic at [webmasters.se] (but read their help first)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the Google crawl rate in Google webmaster tools.